# Working with JArrays in copy activity - Azure Data Factory

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, azure-data-factory

I have created a copy activity which uses a MongoDB JSON file as the data source and I am trying to sink it into an Azure SQL Database.

The issue I have encountered is that my JSON file contains an array of email addresses, and one thing I know is that JArray isn't yet supported by Azure Data Factory and this is the error it produces:

[image]

I have also tried ticking the box below as I found somewhere online stating that if `map the complex values to a string` is ticked it will resolve the issue but this has not worked for me.

[image]

Has anyone been in this position? If so, is there a suitable workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

In Code View of the pipe line

[image]

Ensure source and sink for the erroring field (mail.toAddressList from the error message screen shot) is configured as  below :

```
{
  "source": {
            "path": "$['mail.toAddressList']"
            },
            "sink": {
            "name": "mail.toAddressList",
            "type": "String"
            }
}
```

And also, ensure :

```
    "mapComplexValuesToString": true
```

the above is present. If not add it manually.

Comment: The issue is that for one mail.toAddressList it contains two email addresses inside the array separated by a comma, and when the comma is seen it splits it and puts it into the column to the right, so its not joining the two email addresses together as a string